# What happened to Hoagie?

Tags: discussion, moderation, users

A few moments ago I was talking to [Hoagie](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/332551/hoagie) in the comments of [a question I asked](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/656048/is-there-a-way-to-approximate-an-optotriac-in-circuitjs-falstad). I went back to browse some questions and saw that another answer of theirs had been downvoted without comment, and that they suddenly had 1 reputation. I remember seeing their comments and answers around in recent weeks, and they had (from what I recall) been reasonably well received, so the 1 rep seemed a bit odd to me. Out of curiosity I clicked through to their profile and discovered that they've been banned for a year.

I couldn't see any obvious evidence of an infraction anywhere (although I know mods generally clean stuff up pretty quick), nor do I remember seeing any arguments or disagreements in the last few hours, so it came as a bit of a surprise considering that I was just talking to them 20 minutes earlier.

I know it's usually policy not to discuss specifics of bans, but I was hoping to at least get clarification as to whether this was something the EE SE mods were aware of, or something that perhaps occurred further up the chain. If it's not something that can be commented on, no biggie - I figured I'd ask just in case!

Answer (score 7):

> I know it's usually policy not to discuss specifics of bans

Correct. The more details we give of any suspension, the harder it can be for other site members to view that person in the same way, if they do promise to follow the rules and come back to the site in future.

This is also why there is no public record on someone's profile of previous suspensions. Even with the best intentions, asking about the reasons for someone's suspension on Meta leaves a visible record which wasn't going to be there otherwise!

> I was hoping to at least get clarification as to whether this was something the EE SE mods were aware of

Yes :( Through flags and other ways, we were made aware of an issue. Suspensions (*especially* long ones) are not done lightly.

(I want to ask those site members who flagged the issue *not* to add the details here, for the same reason as I explained above: It can make things harder for the suspended person, if they do promise to follow the rules and come back to the site in future.)

> If it's not something that can be commented on, no biggie - I figured I'd ask just in case!

Thanks for being non-confrontational.

Comment: _"This is also why there is no public record on someone's profile of previous suspensions. [..] asking about the reasons for someone's suspension on Meta leaves a visible record which wasn't going to be there otherwise!"_ I have no intentions to be put in the same situation. But if I ever were, I'd like the mods to remove such a question discussing the reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, and thanks for handling the situation - whatever it was - quickly and tidily.

Answer (score 2):

The account is [temporarily suspended](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) for rule violations.